# Python creating categorical variable error

Tags: python, dataset, categorical-data

I need to create categorical variables for RAM category.

> Basic: RAM [0-4]
>
> Intermediate: RAM [5-8]
>
> Advanced: RAM [8-12]

Command:

```
df['Memory']=pd.cut(df['RAM '], [0,4,8,12], include_lowest=True, labels=['Basic','Intermediate', 'Advaced'])
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-5c93d7c00ba2> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df['Memory']=pd.cut(df['RAM '], [0,4,8,12], include_lowest=True, labels=['Basic', 'Intermediate', 'Advaced'])

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/tile.py in _bins_to_cuts(x, bins, right, labels, precision, include_lowest, dtype, duplicates, ordered)
    425 
    426     side: Literal["left", "right"] = "left" if right else "right"
--> 427     ids = ensure_platform_int(bins.searchsorted(x, side=side))
    428 
    429     if include_lowest:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Could you please help me to fix this? I'm new to Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have numerical-like values in your column `RAM`, so use [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) :

```
df['Memory']= pd.cut(pd.to_numeric(df['RAM '], errors="coerce"), bins=[0,4,8,12],
                     include_lowest=True, labels=['Basic', 'Intermediate', 'Advaced'])
```

With an *example* :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"RAM": np.random.randint(low=1, high=12, size=100).astype(str)})

df["RAM"] = ​pd.to_numeric(df["RAM"], errors="coerce")
​
df["Memory"] = pd.cut(df["RAM"], bins=[0, 4, 8, 12],
                      labels=["Basic", "Intermediate", "Advaced"])
```

​
Output :

```
   RAM        Memory
0    2         Basic
1    2         Basic
2    6  Intermediate
..  ..           ...
97   6  Intermediate
98   1         Basic
99   7  Intermediate

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: now when I want to box-plot them according to price, `sns.boxplot(x='Memory', y='Price', data=df)` I get error `Neither the x nor y variable appears to be numeric.` could you please help me?

Comment: In this case, use `df['RAM '] = pd.to_numeric(df['RAM '], errors="coerce") ;  df['Memory']= pd.cut(df['RAM '], [0,4,8,12], include_lowest=True, ..)` (*like I did in the example*).

Comment: I get error `invalid syntax`

Comment: Refer to the example and remove whitespaces at each empty line (*if you're using Jupyter and copy/pasting*).

Comment: Also, as the first error tells, the column Memory is not numeric. Anyways, if you have a question/issue regarding your plot, you need to open a separate question ;)

Comment: here's screenshot https://prnt.sc/CtX1v6Y0VKu5 I have problem because categories are NaN and invalid syntax... I don't know what I'm using. .. I'm new to Python, could you have a look

Comment: As I said, to avoid moving-target questions, you need to open a separate one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: could you have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75965282/

Comment: AFK, but it seems like you need to extract to numbers in RAM before using pd.cut and boxplot.