# Python categorical variables NaN while creating box-plot

Tags: python, dataset, boxplot, categorical-data

After I successfully created categorical values, their result is NaN.

I used this command:

```
df['Memory']= pd.cut(pd.to_numeric(df['RAM '], errors="coerce"), [0,4,8,12],
                     include_lowest=True, labels=['Basic', 'Intermediate', 'Advaced'])
```

After running `df.head()` here's the table:

[image]

When I try to box-plot them:

```
sns.boxplot(x='Memory', y='Price', data=df['RAM '] = pd.to_numeric(df['RAM '], errors="coerce") ;  df['Memory']= pd.cut(df['RAM '], [0,4,8,12], include_lowest=True, ..)
```

I get error **invalid syntax**

After I run command: `print(df.sample(10).to_dict("list"))`

I get this output:

```
{'Brand': ['Oppo', 'Apple', 'Samsung', 'Apple', 'Xiaomi', 'OnePlus', 'Xiaomi', 'Nokia', 'Samsung', 'Vivo'], 'Model': ['Reno6 Pro 5G', 'iPhone XR', 'Galaxy S20 FE 5G', 'iPhone 12', 'Poco X3 Pro', 'Nord 2', 'Redmi 9 Power', 'G20', 'Galaxy Note20 5G', 'Y33s'], 'Storage': ['128 GB', '64 GB', '128', '128', '128GB', '128GB', '128GB', '64GB', '128', '128GB'], 'RAM': ['12 GB', '3 GB', '6', '4', '6GB', '8GB', '4GB', '4GB', '8', '8GB'], 'ScreenSize': ['6.55', '6.1', '6.5', '6.1', '6.67', '6.43', '6.53', '6.5', '6.7', '6.58'], 'Camera': ['64 + 8 + 2 + 2', '12 + 12', '12+12+8', '12+12', '48MP + 8MP + 2MP + 2MP', '50MP + 8MP + 2MP', '48MP + 8MP + 2MP + 2MP', '48MP + 5MP', '12+64+12', '50MP + 2MP + 2MP'], 'BatteryCapacity': [4500, 2942, 4500, 2815, 5160, 4500, 6000, 5050, 4300, 5000], 'Price': ['659', '499', '699', '799', '$249 ', '$399 ', '$199 ', '$199 ', '1049', '$269 '], 'Memory': ['Advanced', 'Basic', 'Intermediate', 'Basic', 'Intermediate', 'Intermediate', 'Basic', 'Basic', 'Intermediate', 'Intermediate']}
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use this :

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()

df["Memory"] = pd.cut(df["RAM"].str.extract(r"(\d+)", expand=False).astype(float), [0,4,8,12],
                     include_lowest=True, labels=['Basic', 'Intermediate', 'Advanced'])

df["Price"] = df["Price"].str.extract(r"(\d+)", expand=False).astype(float)

sns.boxplot(x="Memory", y="Price", data=df);
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: for your command `sns.boxplot(x="Memory", y="Price", data=df);` I get error `Neither the x nor y variable appears to be numeric.` could you fix it?

Comment: So in this case, can you `print(df.sample(10).to_dict("list"))` (before you do any changes and add/create any new columns) and add it to your question ?

Comment: I added to question... it worked for memory type. it is now basic, intermediate and advanced... thanks, but I cannot print them with boxplot

Comment: I see. Add this line before the boxplot : `df["Price"] = df["Price"].str.extract(r"(\d+)", expand=False).astype(float)` (*see update*).

Comment: thank you very much, could you just give simple explanation... I need to elaborate how this works... just a few words... it would help a lot

Comment: Yes sure! There is only one problem with your dataset/code. The columns `RAM` and `Price` are not *numeric*. That's why `pd.cut` and `sns.boxplot` was throwing errors. The colunm `RAM` has a suffix **GB** and the column `Price` has a dollar sign **$** as a prefix (in some rows). So we used [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to extract the numbers and then [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.7.0/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) to convert the *numeric-like* numbers to real numbers.

Comment: now I'm trying this `sns.jointplot(data=df, x="Price", y="RAM", kind="kde", fill=True)` but I get error `The y variable is categorical, but one of ['numeric', 'datetime'] is required` how to fix this? how to convert RAM to numerical

Comment: Not easy to debug because I don't see your full code but can you add `df["RAM"] = df["RAM"].str.extract(r"(\d+)", expand=False).astype(float)` (*right before making the jointplot*) ?

Comment: I have only one more question. Do you know how to write formula of conditional probability in Python? `P(A|F)=P(A∩Z)/P(Z)` I need with fractions drawn.

Comment: I think you're looking for [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html). Feel free to open a question with the input/expected output.

Comment: here's question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75967622/

Comment: You need to explain the context and eventually share an example with the matching expected output.

Comment: question is closed.. output is as in the picture. Someone wrote a code and after program execution formula was written... but I don't know anything about writing formulas